# How can i convert 1990-12-31T23:59:60Z to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I've tried everything from c solution `strptime_l`  to `NSDataDetector` and `NSDateFormatter`. NSDataDetector returns

> 1990-12-31 11:00:00 +0000

but it's not a good value, So how should I convert it to NSDate.
This is NSDataDetector solution:

```
NSString *myDateString = @"1990-12-31T23:59:60Z";
NSError *error = nil;
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeDate error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:myDateString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [myDateString length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSLog(@"Detected Date: %@", match.date);           // => 2011-11-24 14:00:00 +0000
    NSLog(@"Detected Time Zone: %@", match.timeZone);  // => (null)
    NSLog(@"Detected Duration: %f", match.duration);   // => 0.000000
}
```

This is strptime_l solution.

```
struct tm  sometime;
const char *formatString = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z";
(void) strptime_l("1990-12-31T23:59:60Z", formatString, &sometime, NULL);
NSDate *cDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: mktime(&sometime)];
NSLog(@"NSDate is %@", cDate);
```

And dateFormats is array with date formats,

```
    for (NSString *dateFormat in dateFormats) {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
    detectedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dictionary[@"date"] stringValue]];
    if (detectedDate != nil) {
        break;
    }
}
```

if date format is equal

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
```

setDateFormat:dateFormat return nil for my value but it works for

> 1990-12-31T23:59:59

Comment: Take a look at `ISO8601DateFormatter` by Peter Hosey.

Comment: @luk2302 I don't know why do you need my code, if it's not working? If you want a prove that I tried to solve it by my self I can post.

Comment: You post your code so we can help you fix it.

Comment: Yes, that is one thing - you should show that you have put any effort into trying to solve the question on your own before posting it. And the second reason is that we simply may be able to *improve your* code instead of providing a complete sample on our own.

Comment: Reopened because there is more to this than just the wrong format. FYI - you should update your question showing that the code works with a date string like `1990-12-31T23:59:59` but not `1990-12-31T23:59:60`.

Comment: Just fyi: I did not cast a duplicate close vote.

Comment: @Avi I don't know where you find this lib but it's great!!

Comment: @Salsores The app I work on for my day job uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString * yourDate = @"1990-12-31T23:59:60Z";
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SSZ"];
NSDate * date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:yourDate];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Comment: shouldn't leap seconds roll value to next year ?

Comment: This format is wrong. It should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`.

Comment: @rmaddy your date format returns nil do date, but metronic answer returns 1990-12-31 23:59:00 +0000

Comment: `ss` is for seconds. `SS` is for fractional seconds.

Comment: @rmaddy I know, that's why i didn't try metronic solution, but if i change SS to ss dateFromString return nil.

Comment: @rmaddy that's why I don't think that my question should be marked as duplicated.